# how to set html file in uitextview?

Tags: objective-c, ios5, uitextview, xcode4.3

I did `epub` file unzipped operation.From this operation i get the `META-INF`,`mimetype` and `OPS` files.In the `OPS` file contained the list of `.xml` file.I Want to display those file into `UITextView` with the style of Html formatted operation. I dont want to do this operation in `UIWebView`. Please advice me for `UITextView` operation.

Answer (score 0):

I think it not possible to load html content in uitextView if possible application will be rejected.

So try attributed uitextView to display different style of text. here [EGOTextView](https://github.com/enormego/EGOTextView) link

One option might be to use uiwebview instead of uitextView